# Projective duality

Tags: curves, projective-space

Given a curve how do you intuitively construct the picture of its projective dual? I know points --> lines, lines--> points but for something like the swallowtail this is not really obvious.

Comment: I don't have a answer, but since no one else has said anything, have you tried breaking the curve into a series of lines to gain some intuition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer edited, in response to the comment and a second wind for explaining mathematics:

Let $F(x_0,x_1,x_2)=0$ be the equation for your curve, and take $(y_0,y_1,y_2)$ to be coordinates on $(\mathbb{P}^2)^*$.  Also, assume that $F$ is irreducible and has no linear factors.

Then $y_0 x_0+y_1 x_1+y_2 x_2=0$ is the equation of a general line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ (recall, here $y_0,y_1,y_2$ are fixed, and the $x_i$ are the coordinates on the plane) and we look at the open set of $(\mathbb{P}^2)^*$ where $y_2\neq 0$.  On this open set, we can solve the equation of the line for $x_2$, and look at $g(x_0,x_1)=y_2^n F(x_0,x_1,-\frac{1}{y_2}(y_0x_0+y_1x_1))$, a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ in $x_0,x_1$ with coefficients homogeneous polynomials in the $y_i$.  This polynomial has zeros the intersections of our curve $C$ with the line $L$ we're looking at.

So we want to find points of multiplicity at least two.  So how do we find multiple roots of a polynomial? We take the discriminant! Specifically, we do it for an affinization, and we get a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2n^2-n$ in the $y_i$.

All that's left is to factor the polynomial, and kill all the linear factors, just throw them away, the reasons are explained in more computational detail on my [blogpost](http://rigtriv.wordpress.com/2008/08/04/dual-curves/), and there I also do explicit examples, but the method for calculating the equation of the dual curve is as above.

Comment: Charles: In general, try to avoid having all useful information in an answer contained off-site.